# Local Oracle Client unable to ping/connect to AWS RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I have launched an AWS RDS with Oracle 11g (on port 1521).

Tried to connect using Oracle SQL developer. While testing the connection, getting the following error..

**Error:**
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, connect lapse 0 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.

Explored various options and even opened up the windows outbound port from my local laptop to 1521 port. Nothing helped so far a week.

Comment: Even I have tried with 5 digit port number also (AWS RDS redeployed with 15211)

Comment: Does it take a long time to receive the error, or does it happen immediately? A long wait usually indicates an incorrectly configured Security Group. A fast response indicates that it could access the database, but the connection was rejected for some reason.

Comment: It was too fast.. kind of 0 mill seconds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Found a solution..*

Just launched another windows instance in AWS and modified security groups to make it secure access.

**Security Group changes:**

1. Opened the 1521 port of AWS RDS Oracle to the new windows instance
   alone
2. Windows instance is restricted to only from office public IP.

This does not solve the real problem. However, this solves my purpose..

Thank you all..